# PyDev doesn't show docstring

Tags: python, eclipse, documentation, pydev, docstring

I'm working with PyDev on Eclipse and for some reason it doesn't show docstring when I'm hovering over a function. What also doesn't work, is to jump into a function when pressing F3. Both features work on the computer of my coworker. We tried it for the same functions in the same project.

We compared our settings in Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Hover and they look alike.

Both of us are using Eclipse 4.6.2 and PyDef 5.8.

I really hope someone can help me because it is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the project isn't properly configured in your machine (probably a misconfiguration in the source folders).

Can you attach a screenshot showing the PyDev Package explorer for your project (expanding the project settings) and the editor where F3 is not working to better diagnose it?

Also, do you have some error in your error log?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'm already off work, but I will check it on Tuesday!

Have a nice weekend =)

Comment: You were right! My coworker found the right setting. I posted it as a seperate answer.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another coworker found the answer.

Properties of Project -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH -> Source Folders : Add Source Folder. Choose the file, where your code is.

For some reason, the eclipse of my coworkers did this automatically while mine didn't.